# Resolve a React Native/Web Common import problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, shared, asyncstorage

Merry Chrismas...
I got a React project structured like below

```
- My project
|- common (redux and redux-persist installed)
|- mobile (... with react-native init)
|- web (... with create react app)
```

I tried then to import a basic redux from common in mobile and got an **error**
Here's the code

```
import default_storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"
import default_storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

...
export default (storage = default_storage) => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      auth: persistReducer(
        { key: "auth", storage},
        authReducer
      ),
      event: eventReducer,
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
  return store
};
...
```

When I try to call the function in mobile passing AsyncStorage as parameter
I got an error saying the function couldn't compile because of the fact that there's no part of common that can compile the native part of AsyncStorage.
I tried first with adding fields **resolve** in **babel.config.js** but it actually doesn't work
If someone already did this kinda Structure before, would you share ya code please. Just how to structure the code

Thanks guys